# I cannot access the variable i declared in my class

Tags: c#

This is my c# code

```
namespace abc {
    public class def: SchedulerClient 
    {
        public string key; {}
        public static void send(string abc) 
        {
            lots of code...........
            key = string;
        }
    }    
}
```

I am getting an error when i try to store a string value in my variable key which i have declared as "public".

This is the error i get:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'abc .def.Dkey'

How do i overcome this?

Comment: I recommend you to read MSDN article about static class and static members. It is foundation regarding to your problem in the question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can overcome it by making your method not static:

```
public void send(string abc) 
{
    lots of code...........
    key = stringValue;
}
```

or by making the field static:

```
public static string key;
```

At any rate, I think you need to think about your design and figure out what needs to be static and what doesn't.

Comment: This helped me instantly :)

Answer (score 2):

your method is static but your key is an instance. you cannot access instance properties or methods in a static reference.

either make them both static or make them both non static

Answer (score 1):

Static members are accessible only in static methods and static method can access static members as well as non-static members. Please make the change accordingly.

Comment: Static members are accessible from non-static methods. You are correct though that the opposite in not valid (static methods may only access static members)...unless you pass in an instance of the class as a parameter then you can access non-static private member using that parameter, which is what happens automatically with non-static methods.

Comment: @kevin Brock - Am clear with you comment. But not with the below part,(static methods may only access static members)...unless you pass in an instance of the class as a parameter then you can access non-static private member using that parameter, which is what happens automatically with non-static methods.

Comment: Can you give some more information to get the things correctly?

Comment: That was just a technicality. If you have a static method in a class you can manually pass in a reference to that class (instead of the implied `this`) and still access private members. For instance: `class MyClass { int member; public static addOne(MyClass myObj) { myObj.member++; } }`. No one really does this in-practice; or at least they shouldn't since that should be written as a member method.